# Cheap read-only storage media?

Tags: boot, storage, media

I am looking for a cheap read-only storage medium with around 4 GB space, in most of my cases 1 GB is enough. The idea is to make the device bootable and use it as an replacement for a live CD (CD=slow). One example would be an SD card if I wouldn't have found out that they don't have a real physical write lock and the write lock is often realised in firmware, software etc.

Are there maybe special USB sticks that have a real physical write lock? I never know if there is any malware on the system where I use the medium. CD/DVD would be read-only, but it's so damn slow ): Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Tape can be made read only.

Comment: how would one do that? using a hardware device that provides only read function? it's not suitable for my use cases, I am curious however ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are USB drives that come with write protection switch. One such drive is Ritek Slider ID10

http://www.ritek.com/p2-pro4-ez-funky.asp

Fencepost.com has got list of such devices, more details:
http://www.fencepost.net/2010/03/usb-flash-drives-with-hardware-write-protection/

Comment: The problem is that many of them are no longer available.

Comment: I found the TrekStor CS 4GB and PQI Cool Drive U339 4GB to be available in my country, both around 10 € (~12 USD). There are even more available e.g. in the US, however they are all more expensive anyway, so I don't miss them ;-) So thanks to Shivaranjan :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Look as I have done it.**

Perhaps it is also a solution for you.

**Write protecting by filling up the disk**.

Create temporary files to consume all available free space on the drive.

It’s difficult to infect the drive, If there’s no space to create even a small autorun.inf file.

This is probably better than nothing since it will stop some infections.

[look here how raymond done it](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-fake-dummy-file-on-usb-flash-drive-to-enable-write-protect-and-prevent-modification/)

Comment: Malware can simply delete files, and they certainly do exactly this, these authors are not stupid.

Comment: How malware can get onto a stick that has no space not a byte ?

Comment: malware run on host, then infecting usb stick (first deleting files there).